# Forcing a diagonal edge between two nodes

Tags: graphviz, dot

My question is - is it possible to force a diagonal between two nodes in a diagram?

Assume there is only one link between two nodes.

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=TB
    a -> b;
}
```

This is what is rendered :

[image]

This (mocked up) is what I would like:

[image]

Assume that the rankdir should stay in tact (TB = Top to bottom). I just want to control the direction of the angle of one edge.

I don't see anything in the documentation about how to achieve this (looking [here](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/)).

So my question is, is this behaviour possible, if so how, or am I asking for the impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a hidden node, hidden connection, and proper spline settings, you can get this:

```
digraph G {
    splines=line
    rankdir=TB
    a:s -> b:n;
    i->b [style=invis]  
    a-> i [style=invis]

{rank= same b i [style=invis]}
}
```

[image]

A closer match to your original mock-up, I think.  Is it worth it? You decide. :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably there a different ways to solve this, but without having a clear understanding about your needs in detail, I'm not sure if this would be really helpfull.

For e.g. you can try with the north-east-south-west extension:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=TB
    a:se -> b:nw;
}
```

[image: edge with nesw extension]

Comment: This solution is elegant, but I have to go with the less elegant but more accurately rendered solution from TomServo.

Comment: Absolut perfect. Using invisible nodes was also my first idea, but I was not sure if you can incorporate such "dummy" objects, so I searched a little bit further...